# The dual algebra and linear functionals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that we have a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over $k$ generated by $\{x_1, x_2\}$. Then the dual algebra $A^*$ is generated by $\{x_1^*, x_2^*\}$ where $$x_1^* : A \rightarrow k \space \text{with} \space x_1^*(x_j) = \delta_{1,j}(x_j) 
\\
x_2^* : A \rightarrow k \space \text{with} \space  x_2^*(x_j) = \delta_{2,j}(x_j)$$

Since $A$ is an algebra, it contains an identity element $1_A$. I'm just wondering where $1_A$ is sent by the two maps above. Since $A$ is generated by $\{x_1, x_2\}$, we have  that $1_A = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2$. So $x_1^*(1_A) = a_1$ and $x_2^*(1_A) = a_2$. I feel like $a_1$ and $a_2$ should equal $1$, but I cannot see why...since $1$ is just a linear combination so the coefficients $a_1$ and $a_2$ may not equal $1$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear combination of 1 depends heavily on the chosen base. Note that the formation of dual space $(-)^*$ does not behave well on $k$-algebras in the sense that in general it is not a $k$-algebra again. When considered as a vector space, the element 1 is not fundamentally different form any other element $a \neq 0$.